# How to correctly get specific lines from a large json response?

Tags: java, jackson

i have a large json respose:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "type" : "gif",
    "id" : "BM10Y3Qq3EwK3z8yQd",
    "url" : "https://giphy.com/gifs/ramseysolutions-money-gone-BM10Y3Qq3EwK3z8yQd",
    "slug" : "ramseysolutions-money-gone-BM10Y3Qq3EwK3z8yQd",
    "bitly_gif_url" : "https://gph.is/2mc28WP",
    "bitly_url" : "https://gph.is/2mc28WP",
    "embed_url" : "https://giphy.com/embed/BM10Y3Qq3EwK3z8yQd",
    "username" : "ramseysolutions",
    "source" : "",
    "title" : "rachel cruze money GIF by Ramsey Solutions",
    "rating" : "g",
    "content_url" : "",
    "source_tld" : "",
    "source_post_url" : "",
    "is_sticker" : 0,
    "import_datetime" : "2018-07-12 12:40:11",
    "trending_datetime" : "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "images" : {
      "fixed_width_still" : {
        "height" : "113",
        "size" : "14977",
        "url" : "https://media4.giphy.com/media/BM10Y3Qq3EwK3z8yQd/200w_s.gif?cid=294ee95f49badf517d33e5cd874941ff542e5d2559cf692c&rid=200w_s.gif&ct=g",
        "width" : "200"
      },
      "preview_gif" : {
        "height" : "99",
        "size" : "48529",
        "url" : "https://media4.giphy.com/media/BM10Y3Qq3EwK3z8yQd/giphy-preview.gif?cid=294ee95f49badf517d33e5cd874941ff542e5d2559cf692c&rid=giphy-preview.gif&ct=g",
        "width" : "176"
      },
      
     ...
```

And I want to get out of there only `data -> url` and `data -> embed_url` .
How can this be done correctly?
i try add `@JsonProperty to setter`  :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class GifUrlDto {
    private String url;
    private String embedUrl;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setUrl(Map<String, String> data) {
        this.url =data.get("url");
        this.embedUrl = data.get("embed_url");
    }
}
```

When I try to return it from the function:

```
@GetMapping("/random")
    GifUrlDto getRandomGByExchangeRates();
```

then  i get an error :

```
 Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 665] (through reference chain: com.alfa.bank.project.gifAndExchangeRate.dto.GifUrlDto["data"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["images"])] with root cause
```

Do I need to make a desiarilizer somehow, or can I do it better?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better at using a json xpath like API such as https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath ?

Comment: Can't you use `com.google.gson.JsonParser` to parse the Json into required value?

Comment: @Debanjan can gson easily get these 2 lines?

Comment: You can deserialise it to a `Map<String, Object>` using ObjectMapper.

Comment: @Omegon yes you can pick up the required values from the paths using JsonParser. Something along the lines of this:

`final JsonObject elementObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
  final String url = elementObject.get("url").getAsString();
`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get out of there only data -> url and data -> embed_url. Do
> I need to make a desiarilizer somehow, or can I do it better?

You can do it either without a deserializer or with a deserializer. Without a deserializer you can isolate the part of the json file you are interested and  convert it to a `JsonNode` object using the [`JsonNode#at`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#at-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonPointer-) method (good if you have to extract properties once in your code):

```
JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(json).at("/data");
String url = data.get("url").asText(); //<--url is a string
String embedUrl = data.get("embed_url").asText();//<-- embed_url is a string
GifUrlDto dto = new GifUrlDto(url, embedUrl);
```

You can also write a specific deserializer for the `GifUrlDto` class reusing the above code (good if you have to deserialize more than one object):

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonDeserialize(using = GifUrlDtoDeserializer.class)//<--added annotation
public class GifUrlDto {
    private String url;
    private String embedUrl;
}

public class GifUrlDtoDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<GifUrlDto>{

    public GifUrlDtoDeserializer() {
        super(GifUrlDto.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GifUrlDto deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode root = codec.readTree(jp);
        JsonNode data = root.at("/data");
        String url = data.get("url").asText();
        String embedUrl = data.get("embed_url").asText();
        return new GifUrlDto(url, embedUrl); 
    }
}

//using the deserializer
GifUrlDto dto = mapper.readValue(json, GifUrlDto.class);
```